# Question about initial_position in Fortress

Tags: ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to figure how to have an initial position without change the system or position coordination.

I originally thought `<initial_position>` would do the trick in joint_controller, but it doesn't do anything.

What is other way to load the initial position? I wanted to load two servos in 90 degree instead of zero degree.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27798/question-about-initial_position-in-fortress/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

https://community.gazebosim.org/t/new-ignition-releases-2022-04-13-fortress-edifice/1367

Closing this now

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2022-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0